# Writing csv with space delimiter and new column headers in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add 4 column headers in 300 csv files (without headers and columns but in each row, numbers are separated by spaces). But currently I just need to do it in one. Following is my code.rval_range is just an array with numbers that are stored as generated file names.

```
   rval_range = arange(0.,2,.1)
   for new_rval in rval_range:
        with open('output_sample_221119-rval-' + str(new_rval)+'/output_dataset_coordinates.csv', 'r') as infile:
            readie=csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
            with open('output_sample_221119-rval-' + str(new_rval)+'/output_dataset_coordinates1.csv', 'wt') as output:
                 outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=' ')            
                 for row in readie:
                          writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=["X", "Y", "Z", "Discharge"])
                          writer.writeheader()
                          outwriter.writerow(row)
```

But this gives me a csv where under one column with header "X" all the four values for all rows fall. Other columns with headers "Y","Z" and "Discharge" have NaN as values for all rows.

Comment: What is the question? what is the problem or error?

Comment: I don't get the result as expected : 4 new column headers with their respective values in the columns. I instead get all the values under one column "X" and NaN values under all the other column headers

Comment: Are you sure the file you're reading from is space delimited?

Comment: Can you post an example of a csv file you use?